# If a recipe calls for Pectin NH can I use other pectin?

Tags: pectin, glaze

I am making this yule log for christmas which requires pectin NH for the glaze.  Can I use any other normal pectin instead of the pectin NH and have the same glossy finish?

Comment: See related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24205/what-is-the-difference-between-pectin-and-pectin-nh

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

Different pectins set under different conditions. Some require calcium, others require a high percentage of sugar. All have their own optimal pH range.

When a recipe is optimised for one type of pectin, other types won't set properly. Normally, you cannot substitute in any direction.

The linked question from Jolenealaska's comment provides further information.